# URLSession error

Tags: json, swift, swift3, urlsession

I am using a function which was actually written for swift 2. I've made moderations for swift 3. But I keep getting the error:

> URLSession' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type
>   'URLSession!

My code looks like this:

```
func downloadItems() {

        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var session: URLSession!
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default


        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)


        let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URL)

        task.resume()
    }
```

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why is `URLSession` `var` and implicit unwrapped optional? `URLSession(configuration...` returns non-optional. And Swift 3 introduces `URL`  replacing `NSURL`

Comment: Seems ok, works in playground. Perhaps you need a Clean / Clean Build Folder, or there are syntax errors earlier in the file.

Comment: that's weird in Playground I get the same error. Also I have fixed all other issues in my project. 

I tried this as well but still have the same issue:

func downloadItems() {
        
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        var session: URLSession
        
        session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URL)
        
        task.resume()   
    }

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
 session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Do this:

```
   session = {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        return session
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your URLSession functions with those:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    self.data.append(data as Data)  
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else {
        print("Data downloaded")
        self.parseJSON()
    }
}
```