# URLSession Error Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, urlsession

I have the following code:

```
func downloadItems() {

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var session: URLSession!
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URL)

    task.resume()

}
```

This is from an older project online, and Swift is giving me this error code:

> 'URLSession' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type 'URLSession!'.

I've found other people asking about this on Stock Overflow, but all the answers are for older versions of Swift, and result in other errors.

Here are the other questions I found:

[How to set URLSession Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634475/how-to-set-urlsession-swift-3)

[URLSession error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347832/urlsession-error)

Comment: Did you try to clean and build the project and also try to replace `let url: NSURL(string: urlPath)!` with `let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!` and then you also don't need to cast you NSURL to an URL. Instead of `session.dataTask(with: url as URL)` you just need to use `session.dataTask(with: url)`

Comment: @ronatory I did everything you suggested but there is no change to the error message.

Comment: ok sad. What Xcode version do you have?

Comment: @ronatory 8.2.1

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlPath!))
request.httpMethod = "GET"
task1 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error 

in guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 

// check for fundamental networking error

   print("error=\(error)")

 return

}

if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {


   // check for http errors

   print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")

   print("response = \(response)")

}

let json=JSON(data: data);

self.json=json;

self.parse(json: json)

}

task1.resume()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!